# How do I speed up memory mapped files over network?

Tags: network-share, file-sharing, network-speed

Memory mapping a file on a SMB file share causes it to be transferred in its entirety before the call returns. For large files, this causes the application to lock up for a long period of time. How do I fix this?

"Use X instead of SMB" is a valid answer.

Edit: Any application, any file. I'm not trying to solve a specific case. Memory mapping a file is a way of opening it so that it appears to the application as part of the working memory - you access the file as if it's an array.

Comment: Why not to put the file on a local filesystem?

Comment: Which application? Which file? Memory mapped what? Fix what?

Comment: So little information.  Are you looking for something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005791/linux-what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-reading-a-file-from-a-nas-and-sending-ov/6005919#6005919)?

Comment: This question is clear, precise, complete, specific and practical and I would hope for a solution. Use NFS instead of SMB is a partial answer as is use a local file system, but these are outside of the control of users of "clusters" or "supercomputers", and I had had problems with NFS too. What application? my research across a cluster of 1000 processors! What file? several terabyte of (streamed/buffered) AV and ontological data! What does it matter? I need a solution that allows simultaneous reading & update of small independent possibly adjacent possibly conjointly blocked parts of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an artifact of the operating system's implementation of `mmap`, not anything to do with the network protocol in use (as much as I love to rag on SMB...).  SMB is more than capable of reading random chunks out of a file, therefore there's no reason it couldn't read chunks as they're requested.  I don't have an SMB server accessable at this moment to verify it, but I do have an NFS server, and I just tried to `mmap` a 1.7GB file and it returned instantaneously, so at the very least it certainly isn't some inherent limitation in the concept of mmap.